# YouTube Counter Doesn't Count New Views

Tags: youtube

I have two videos for which the counters were frozen in error.  I live in a community housing situation where people share a machine. Despite different logins, we are all treated as one viewer.  No one's views of my videos are ever counted among my colleagues, and there are many of us.  As well, friends outside the community have reported that their views are also not being counted. So far, over 10 people have told me they checked the counter on visiting my videos, and they were not counted.  I do not add commercials to my posts.

Meanwhile, I visited similar videos that do have commercials attached, and no matter how many times I clicked on the videos, plus no matter how briefly I viewed them, all my visits were counted.  Either the program for detecting "invalid" views is poor, or there is uneven application of standards.

Comment: And the videos are always viewed on the YouTube website (ie. not embedded or anything like that)?

Answer (score 2):

YouTube view counts are complicated by their efforts to reduce view-count spam, by delays in propagating data through a very large set of servers, and other factors.

See for example [Frozen View Count](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2991785?hl=en&rd=1) and [An Update On Our View Counts](http://youtube-global.blogspot.com/2009/03/update-on-our-view-counts.html).